# How to run Umbraco Locally from Live Site

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I just started working in a company, and I am very new to Umbraco. They had a developer before who may have forgotten to keep the repository up to date. Its missing a lot of files.

I was wondering if there is a way from Umbraco interface (Live Site) to download everything and run Umbraco Locally? I have the access to the server and the Umbraco (Live Site) interface.

**NOTE:** This is my first time ever working with Umbraco. Step by step guide will be really helpful for me.

---

Yes, I have tried the `dotnet restore`. That is the first thing I did. It genuinely missing the files. I have to make changes directly to the template on the production, which sucks so bad!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via Umbraco. In Umbraco the admin interface is commonly referred to as "backoffice", BTW :-)

Have you tried restoring Nuget packages in your solution (from repo)? After that you build and run the website - and might have to go through the Umbraco installation locally if all the Umbraco files aren't in the repo, but hopefully you can click "Customize" during installation and connect to an up-to-date database (or make a copy of the one in production) which then should get you going pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes, `dotnet restore` was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have access to the server - it however isn't really clear if you have access to the actual server or if you simply have access to the backoffice.

If you have access to the server then this is fairly simple:
If the previous developer hasn't been committing the latest changes, you can get the missing files currently deployed to live, by fetching them directly off the server and then putting them in your local site.

If you do not have access to the server but only to the backoffice, there's not an easy way to get the files currently running in the site. I think the best approach here would be to put some code in a template, allowing you to list and fetch files from the filesystem. It is however a bit of manual work so getting access to the server would likely be a much faster solution.

You would however also need a copy of the database running the site, to be able to run the site on your local machine.

As a last note, I would make sure to check the repository again just to be completely sure the files aren't actually already in there somewhere. It may just be that you need to execute some sort of build script, copying these files to the correct locations as part of the build process.

Comment: Another possible solution to get the files out of the existing site via the backoffice would be to create a package from the package section. Here you could include all the folders on the file system and save/publish the package. Then install this package in a new blank instance of Umbraco on your local machine and it should put the files in the same locations where you can then copy them from.